# Accessing Microsoft Word document from a C++ program

Tags: c++, windows, ms-word

I need to read from a MS Word document, write into it and format it from a C++ program. How can I do that? What technologies exist to complete such tasks?

This should be done in VS2010 using diffrent sorts of Microsoft technologies. I can't use any additional proprietary libraries besides the standard ones.

Comment: What's the format?- Word has/uses several.

Comment: Could you explain how you can do it using Microsoft technologies while not using any proprietary library?  AFAIK, most of Microsoft libraries ARE prorprietary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technology you want is probably COM (Component Object Model). The terminology that Microsoft use is, it seems, "Office Automation", so you might find more information by searching for that.

I think, though, that you need to have Microsoft Office installed to use this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa188489%28v=office.10%29.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196776

Comment: AFAIK, *COM* is **proprietary** so it should not fit the OP requirements of avoiding proprietary libraries...

Comment: The OP is using VS2010 and says he wants to use Microsoft technologies, so my guess is that he's only avoiding proprietary libraries from vendors other than Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use proprietary technologies (and Microsoft technologies are very often proprietary), you could consider using (parts of) [libreoffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/), a free (as in speech) word processor, coded mostly in C++, and able to process Microsoft proprietary Word format.